# How to do I calculate how much sand and cement needed for bedding mortar

Tags: mortar, cement

I need to make some bedding mortar for laying coping stones on a brick wall

Ive calculated the volume of mortar needed

12m x 0.41m x 0.03m = 0.1476 m3

I buy cement and sand in 25 kg bags and would use 1-4 cement/sand ratio
So 125kg would be 1 bag of cement to 4 bags of sand

but how to I equate weight with volume ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can assume the cement mix is about the same density as sand.  It won't be exact, but since the cement is the smaller proportion the error won't be great.

According to [this site](http://www.traditionaloven.com/building/beach-sand/convert-cubic-metre-beach-sand-m3-to-kg-of-beach-sand.html), 1 cubic meter of beach sand weighs 1,529.20 kg.

Answer (score 0):

An 80 pound bag is about half a cubic foot (sorry, as for metric, you're on your own).

> The finished volume of an 80# bag of Sacrete or Quikrete (pre-mixed cement, sand and gravel) is **0.6 cubic foot (stated on the bag)**. There are 27 cubic feet in a cubic yard. Dividing 27 cubic feet by the volume of the bag will give you the number of bags you need. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20many%20yards%20is%20a%20bag%20of%20concrete&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score -1):

Sand and cement are always mixed by volume. The mix is 1:3.